# Error "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" while using with sshpass

Tags: shell, sudo, sshpass

I want to write a script in which I need to get the content of a file from different machine `192.168.0.2` without enterging the password so I used `sshpass` with the following command :

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.2 " ls /root/path/of/file"
```

Output :

```
ls: cannot access '/root/path/of/file': Permission denied
```

I get it because I sidn't login as a `root` user. So I tried :

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.2 "sudo ls /root/path/of/file"
```

Output :

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As details by this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122624) on StackExchange, the `/etc/sudoers` file on the remote host is likely disallowing you from running sudo commands without a tty. It also has a number of detailed recommendations for working around the problem if you can't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ssh -t` which would allocate a tty for you.

Comment: Using `sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.2 " ls /root/path/of/file"` prompts `[sudo] password for user:`. I want that the password should be added automatically.

Comment: Then you need to 1) confiugre sudo for password-less usage or 2) use tools like [tag:expect].